# Find coordinates of points within overlapping circles

Tags: r, algorithm, data.table, computational-geometry, voronoi

Lets say I have many (lon,lat) points on a globe (e.g. 1,000,000 points). Then I
draw a circle around each point and would like to find a new point within
each overlapping area. Now I am interested in the (lon,lat) coordinates
of the new points.

The following gives an illustration of what I would like to achieve:

```r
# Original points (3 points)
lon <- c(6.3, 6.9, 6.9)
lat <- c(53, 53.1, 52.4)
df <- data.frame(lat = lat, lon = lon, r = .5)
```

Now I would like to create a new data.frame with (lon,lat) points within overlapping circles:

```r
# Example of new points within overlapping areas
df_new <- data.frame(
  lat = c(52.4, 53.1, 53, 53, 52.6, 52.75, 52.75),
  lon = c(6.9, 6.9, 6.3, 6.6, 6.5, 6.65, 7)
)
```

How can I achieve this? The exact location of the red point doesn't matter, the only constraint is that the red point should be within the intersection. I prefer a data.table solution (and not with sf or sp). Or is it possible to solve this using Voronoi Diagrams?

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Nice challenge! How would you feel about mapping it to a coordinate grid so that distances in x and y were equal? I'm considering this myself for stop-detection algorithms. In theory you can use this to "window" acceptable coordinates because it's just the equation for a circle.

Comment: Do they have the same radius ?

Comment: In the Computational Geometry literature, this should be known as an *arrangement of circles* (not *circle packing*). There does not seem to be much material on this topic.

Comment: @DanielleMcCool Yes, it would be perfect to first transform the coordinates to a coordinate grid with equal x and y values

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes all circles have the same radius. The radius is small, like 300 meters.

Comment: Telling the value is not informative if we don't know the density of points.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Do you have a suggestion for a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you want but it might help you. Code below takes buffer around each point in `df` of 50 km, finds overlaping geometries and points in `df_new` that are in:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(sf)

lon <- c(6.3, 6.9, 6.9)
lat <- c(53, 53.1, 52.4)
df <- data.frame(lat = lat, lon = lon, r = .5) 

df_new <- data.frame(
  lat = c(52.4, 53.1, 53, 53, 52.6, 52.75, 52.75),
  lon = c(6.9, 6.9, 6.3, 6.6, 6.5, 6.65, 7)
) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) 


circle_df <- df %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  st_transform(3035) %>%
  st_buffer(dist = units::set_units(50, "kilometers"))


in_intersection <- st_intersection(circle_df) %>% 
  filter(n.overlaps == 2) %>%
  st_transform(4326) %>%
  st_within(df_new, .) %>%
  map_lgl(is_empty) %>%
  "!"() %>%
  which() %>%
  slice(df_new, .) 

plot(st_geometry(circle_df %>% st_transform(4326)))
plot(st_geometry(in_intersection), add = TRUE)
```

[image]

I'm not sure how to make circles around points where distance is difference in longitude and latitude (that woudn't be circle but some kind of ellipse). What you can try to do is to approximate radius by taking distance from points `(lon, lat)` and `(lon, lat-r)` (one way of doing it) and passing that distance for buffer.

```
df <- df %>% mutate(lat1 = lat - r) 
df1 <- df %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)  
df2 <- df %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat1"), crs = 4326)   
d <- st_distance(df1, df2, by_element = TRUE)

circle_df <- df1 %>%
  st_transform(3035) %>%
  st_buffer(dist = d)
```

and continuing from here as in upper example. I'm not sure how scalable this is (you have a lot of points).

**edit**

```
circle_df <- df %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  st_transform(3035) %>%
  st_buffer(dist = units::set_units(50, "kilometers"))

points_within <- st_intersection(circle_df) %>%
  st_centroid()

df_new <- points_within %>%
  st_transform(4326) %>%
  st_coordinates() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  setNames(c("lon", "lat"))

plot(st_geometry(circle_df))
plot(st_geometry(points_within), add = TRUE)
```

[image]

If you want points only in intersections add `filter(n.overlaps > 1)` after `st_centroid()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very much appreciated. However I am looking to find the points in df_new itself (these points are not given), and not whether the points in df_new are within a circle

Comment: That shouldn't be hard to modify, see edit.